# Python decorators: howto list wrapped functions by decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

Is that possible to use python decorators to mark a method, and get it for the later use, if I don't know the name of the wrapped function?

Here is the example, and I don't know the name of method_with_custom_name:

```
@run_this_method
def method_with_custom_name(my_arg):
    return "The args is: " + my_arg

def _init_and_run():
    # Here, I want to get and call method_with_custom_name
    # but I don't know it's name, 
    # so the next line isn't valid.
    return run_this_method()(my_arg_value)

def run_this_method(m):
    def w(my_arg):
        _do_some_magic(my_arg, m)
    return w

def _do_some_magic(callback_arg, callback):
     if some_checks():
          callback(callback_arg)
```

So how can I get a list of methods wrapped with `@run_this_method`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to track all functions and methods decorated with your decorator you need to create global variable to register all such functions and methods. I've modified your code:

```
funcs_registry = [] #List of all functions decorated with @run_this_method
def run_this_method(m):
    global functions_registry
    funcs_registry.append(m) #Add function/method to the registry

    def w(my_arg):
        _do_some_magic(my_arg, m)
    return w

def _do_some_magic(callback_arg, callback):
    if some_checks():
        callback(callback_arg)

@run_this_method
def method_with_custom_name(my_arg):
    return "The args is: " + my_arg

def _init_and_run():
    global functions_registry

    # Here you can iterate over "functions_registry"
    # and do something with each function/method in it
    for m in functions_registry:
        print(m.__name__)
```

Instead of using global variable `functions_registry` you can create class to be used as decorator and register functions in entity field. Something like this:

```
class FunDecorator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.registry = []

    def __call__(self, m):
        "This method is called when some method is decorated"
        self.registry.append(m) #Add function/method to the registry

        def w(my_arg):
            _do_some_magic(my_arg, m)
        return w

run_this_method = FunDecorator() #Create class instance to be used as decorator

@run_this_method
def method_with_custom_name(my_arg):
    return "The args is: " + my_arg

#do some magic with each decorated method:
for m in run_this_method.registry:
    print(m.__name__)
```

Comment: No, you do not need to introduce global state to do this, any more than you ever need to introduce global state to track anything in an app.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, could clarrify how it's possible to implement without having global state?

Comment: A decorator is an object. Anything you store on that object can be kept around as long as you have an instance of that object. It does not require global variables, as any number of mature Python projects will show.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (how to decorate a method with an unknown name?) then it is totally possible.

```
@decorator
def foo(bar):
  pass
```

is syntastic sugar for

```
def foo(bar):
  pass
foo = decorator(foo)
```

So in your case you should just do:

```
method_with_custom_name = run_this_method(method_with_custom_name)
```

The example you provided is confusing, though. Why don't you know the name of method_with_custom_name? It is right there. It is called method_with_custom_name. To use the decorated version later, you just call method_with_custom_name.

Comment: Because, I'm writing a lib, and somebody else will write `method_with_custom_name` and `another_method_with_custom_name`